# Loading external files into index template by clicking links that are inside external files

Tags: jquery, html, css

Context:
The jquery script below loads an external file into a `div` within my index template depending on which link a user clicks.

Problem:
The links within the external files don't adhere to the jquery script or CSS styling because they cannot load the new external file into the `div` located within the index template

jquery:

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
    $("#content").load("content/index_content.php");

    $('a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#nav div").removeClass("active");
        $(this).children("div").addClass("active");
        $('#content').load($(this).attr('href'));
        return false;
    )};
)};
```

Comment: The runnable code feature is for code that runs. I modified it not be just a snippet. And sorry, you did rant and it's hard to understand the problem.

Comment: @JuanMendes Sorry, so that jquery allows loading external files into a div in index. The external files have links to other external files. The problem is, the links within the external files, when clicked, don't adhere to the jquery script because they cannot see the `<div id="content"></div>` that is located on the index page

Comment: Adding comments won't help, you should reword your question with fewer words and more code. I think adding the HTML structure of the page and of the pages being loaded may help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're referring to event delegation. (See: https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Your current jQuery is run on window load, and therefore any elements added after this don't have the event attached to them. You can solve this by adding the event listener to a parent element and letting the event delegate to a child.

You'll need to change your `$('a').click(function(e){` to something like `$(document).on('click', 'a', function(e) {` which means the event will fire any time an anchor tag is clicked within the document.

e.g.

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
    $("#content").load("content/index_content.php");

    $(document).on('click', 'a', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#nav div").removeClass("active");
        $(this).children("div").addClass("active");
        $('#content').load($(this).attr('href'));
        return false;
    )};
)};
```

Comment: that works absolutely perfectly. Before your answer I actually solved the issue by using the deprecated .delegate() method, but your solution is far cleaner, thank you. Any insight into why external links will not load? I'm not trying to load the external links into my site, but rather have them act as normal links and redirect the user to that page

Comment: @Jay the example provided is targeting any link within the document and the `e.preventDefault()` and `return false` prevents links from working as they usually should. You can narrow down the elements being targeted by changing the `'a'` to, for example, `'#nav a'`. That means only links within `#nav` will be targeted instead of all links.